# DataTable clearFilter() not working properly

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a complicate JSF that contain dataTable with filter in each one of the columns.
In order to make sure that the generate button will fetch all the data first I need to clear all the filters  when the user press the button.

I try to do use onclick but then I couldn’t see the blockUI I also try on complete (ajax) but again it was not working properly with all the other items (blockUI ,message).
I decided to try to clear the filters via server side but only dataTable.reset() is working.

I have no more ideas how to clean the filters ???

Is this API working ?

Appreciate your help

Thanks

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width: 100%">
    <p:panel id="vt-panel">
        <h:panelGrid columns="5" cellpadding="2" >  
            <h:outputText value="Start Date"  />
            <p:calendar id="vt-start" value="#{vtRepBean.startDate}" binding="#{startDateComponent}" maxlength="9" size="9" pattern="dd-MMM-yy" title="dd-MMM-yy" required="true" maxdate="#{vtRepBean.endDate}">
                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{vtRepBean.handleStartDateSelect}" update=":mainForm:vt-end"/>
            </p:calendar>
            <h:outputText value="End Date"  />
            <p:calendar id="vt-end" value="#{vtRepBean.endDate}" maxlength="9" size="9" pattern="dd-MMM-yy" title="dd-MMM-yy" required="true" mindate="#{vtRepBean.startDate}">
                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{vtRepBean.handleEndDateSelect}" update=":mainForm:vt-start"/>
            </p:calendar>
            <p:commandButton
                id="genVtBtn"
                value="Generate"
                actionListener="#{vtRepBean.handleVTGenerateButton}"
                update=":mainForm:vt-panel,:mainForm:vt-panel-table">
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:panelGrid> 
<p:growl id="vt_message" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
<h:panelGroup id="vt-panel-table">
    <p:dataTable id="vtDataTable"
                 widgetVar="vtWidget"
                 var="reportObject"
                 value="#{vtRepBean.reportObjectsList}"
                 rendered="#{vtRepBean.renderVTReport}"
                 filteredValue="#{vtRepBean.filteredVTList}"
                 paginator="true"
                 paginatorPosition="bottom"
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="50,100,200"
                 rows="50"
                 style="width: 100%"> 
        <p:columnGroup type="header"> 
            <p:row>  
                <p:column colspan="5" headerText="VT request"/> 
                <p:column colspan="1" headerText="Dis" /> 
            </p:row>  
            <p:row>  
                <p:column headerText="CREATE DATE" sortBy="#{reportObject.log.createDate}" filterBy="#{reportObject.log.createDate}" filterMatchMode="contains"/>  
                <p:column headerText="IP" sortBy="#{reportObject.log.ip}" filterBy="#{reportObject.log.ip}" filterMatchMode="contains"/>    
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>
        <p:column >  
            <h:outputText value="#{reportObject.log.createDate}"/>  
        </p:column>
        <p:column >  
            <h:outputText value="#{reportObject.log.ip}"/>  
        </p:column>    
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:commandLink rendered="#{vtRepBean.renderVTReport}" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(showStatus, hideStatus)">  
        <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/excel.png" title="excel" style="border-color: white"/>  
        <p:dataExporter id="xlsReport"
                        type="xls" 
                        target="vtDataTable"
                        fileName="VTReport"
                        postProcessor="#{vtRepBean.postProcessXLS}"/>
    </p:commandLink>
</h:panelGroup>
<p:blockUI widgetVar="blockVTPanel" trigger="genvtBtn" block="vt-panel">
    <div class="disable-scroll">
        <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/ajax-loader.gif"/> 
    </div>
</p:blockUI>
```

```
     DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("mainForm:vtDecomDataTable");
        if (!dataTable.getFilters().isEmpty()) {
            logger.info("dataTable.getFilters().isEmpty() :" + dataTable.getFilters().isEmpty());

            dataTable.getFilters().clear();// not working
            dataTable.getFilteredValue().clear();// not working
            dataTable.setFilteredValue(null);// not working
            dataTable.setFilters(null);// not working
            dataTable.setFilterMetadata(null);// not working 

            dataTable.reset();// working 

            RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            requestContext.update("mainForm:vtDecomDataTable");

        }
```

Comment: Where is `vtDecomDataTable` in your `<p:dataTable>`

Comment: Sorry typo mistake 

It’s should be “requestContext.update("mainForm:vtDataTable")”

Comment: Same issue here, no answer for this genius guy ?

Comment: Have you tried to empty `filteredVTList` and then update the datatable ?

Comment: @HatemAlimam :     public void resetFilterDatatable( {filteredVTList = null;} works for the datatable, but the filter column input is not cleared, this is the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is how i solved my problem.

```
 RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
 requestContext.execute("PF('widget_orderDataTable').clearFilters()");
```

Hope its help.

Comment: Use this for primefaces 6.x PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('widget_orderDataTable').clearFilters()");

Answer (score 37):

To clear all the inputs of the filters you can do it by javascript:

```xhtml
<p:commandButton onclick="PF('vtWidget').clearFilters()" />
```

`vtWidget` is the widgetVar of the datatable.

Basically `clearFilters()` will clear the fields for you and call `filter()`, and the filter function would update your datatable, which in turns will empty the filtered list.

Note: This would work only if the filters were `inputText`. If you have custom components then you should implement your own clear based on the components that you have.

Sometimes if you have custom components, you need to empty the filtered list manually, as you did in the comments!

Comment: I never see a filter were inputText, I'm in the same case than the showcase (but without the global filter inputText) : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml. I want to clear my column filter ( <p:column id="first_column" filterBy="first_filter" >) which are Combobox or text input.

Comment: you've said it yourself "text input" which is inputText .. which is a normal html input (auto generated) ...  in-fact if you get the onclick code and execute it in the console in the showcase page, you would have the result you want... so to test go to http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml write anything in the id filter, now open your console and execute this `PF('carsTable').clearFilters()`...

Comment: "If you have custom components then you should implement your own clear based on the components that you have." how would you do this?

Comment: Again it depends on the custom components you have, each one might have a case @PieterDeBie

Answer (score 15):

For clearing custom filters you can use primefaces [resetInput](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/resetInput.xhtml), along with clearFilters() discussed in other answers, and a custom actionListener method. See code snippets below:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" widgetVar="dataTable"
    value="#{bean.listOfObjects}" var="object">

<p:commandButton value="Clear All Filters"
    onclick="PF('dataTable').clearFilters()" 
    actionListener="#{controller.clearAllFilters}"
    update="dataTable">
    <p:resetInput target="dataTable" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Controller.java

```
public void clearAllFilters() {

    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("form:dataTable");
    if (!dataTable.getFilters().isEmpty()) {
        dataTable.reset();

        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        requestContext.update("form:dataTable");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps anyone looking to clear custom filters.

Comment: I wonder if you have to add `:` in front of your id in Java code as you have to do with EL code? So the resulting string is `":form:dataTable"`. Plus if you use `p:page id="foo"` you may also have to add that to the ids: `":foo:form:dataTable"`.

Comment: @Roland: no not needed. The id's in the `requestContext.update` are **always** treated as absolute.

Comment: Using <p:ajax onsuccess="PF('datatable').clearFilters()"></p:ajax> works great at the moment of Delete, but when I add new object to the table doesn't work properly, but with your solution works perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @ElíGiacomelli any idea why clearFilters () doesn't work properly? I am trying to clear the filters for a p:datatable inside a dialog on the close of the dialog. And both the solutions, clearFilters () and that by avey is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

For Primefaces 7 and above, use the following:

```
public void clearAllFilters() {

    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("form:dataTable");
    if (!dataTable.getFilters().isEmpty()) {
        dataTable.reset();

        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("form:dataTable");
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me cause needed to do the clearFilter without doing an ajax call with <p:commandButton onclick="PF('vtWidget').clearFilters()" />, thank you marcel :)