# How to find an component ID including the composite component ID from backing bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component, clientid

Our project using PF5.1, we have a dataTable in a composite component. So after page rendering. the dataTable's id kind of like j_idt123:tableForm:tableId.

We need to clear the table filter stuff before searching. I tried use the following code to find it in the backing bean but it returns `null`.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("tableId");
```

As this component will be used in different xhtml file, this "j_idt123" thing got changed every time. What will be the right way to get the table ?

Comment: You may want to take a step back and re-ask about specifically the *"We need to clear the table filter stuff before searching"* problem instead of about the attempted solution to that problem. There may be better ways to solve tht "filter stuff" problem which doesn't require manually grabbing components from the tree (which you should try to avoid to all extent inside a backing bean).

Comment: @BalusC I tried to clear the table filtering by using PF('datatableWidgetVar').clearFilters() but seems not working, then I'm thinking to clear it on the server side. It will work when the table id is static but not sure how can get the id then that datatable in composite componet.

Comment: maybe the top answer of this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797476/datatable-clearfilter-not-working-properly

Comment: @sinclair thanks. I will accept your answser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"j_idt123" is a generated id for components which do not specify their own.
Just give the parent-container of "tableForm" an id.

Comment: I have already gave an Id to tableForm, j_idt123 comes from the composite component contains the tableForm.

Comment: The answer didn't said you have to specify it on the `tableForm`, but on its parent container.